# Xamarin Community Toolkit's EventToCommandBehavior doesn't fire within a ListView

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a ListView with an ObservableCollection as the ItemsSource. Amongst others I have a CheckBox in the ListView with its IsChecked-Property bound to the collection (for simplicity I've just stated the CheckBox in the code below). Now I would like to implement EventToCommandBehavior from XCT to the CheckBox, though the Command won't fire. If I put the CheckBox outside of the ListView the EventToCommandBehavior fires though (of course without all the reference and source, just stating Command="{Binding ButtonLoeschenEnableDisableCommand})...

```
 <ContentPage x:Name="ContentPageAnzeigenBearbeiten" 
             Title="Anzeigen &amp; Bearbeiten">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:LesezeichenViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>-->
    <Grid >
            <ListView x:Name="listViewBookmarks"
                    HasUnevenRows="True"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Bookmarks}"
                    CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalOptions="End">
                                    <CheckBox.Behaviors>
                                        <xct:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="CheckedChanged" 
                                            Command="{Binding LesezeichenViewModel.ButtonLoeschenEnableDisableCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=ContentPageAnzeigenBearbeiten}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                    </CheckBox.Behaviors>
                                </CheckBox>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage >
```

Comment: you need to use a relative binding - the BindingContext of each item in a templated control is different than when used directly in a page or layout

Comment: Cool. I will look it up. Maybe u have a good reference/link?

Comment: the official docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings

Comment: Unfortunately the relative binding crashes with xct's EventToCommandBehavior. I've added a button to my page with the relative binding to test it and it works like a charm. :/

Comment: 1) There is almost certainly an **error message in VS' Output pane**, related to that crash. 2) If the relative binding "works like a charm" in a button that is not part of the item template - then you are using a binding path that is sensible relative to the button's location, but is meaningless inside an item template. See #1, which should be a message telling you it couldn't find anything with that path. **Show the relative path you tried.** Does it match what is described in that link under the example with `ListView.ItemTemplate`?

Comment: It says: **System.InvalidOperationException:** 'Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.' The applications crashes as soon I am entering the page. I don't even have to check the box. I've added a button to the ListView with the relative binding and it works also in this case.